# Magento 1.9 Cron.php Works, Cron.sh Does Not

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I've tried many solutions, but can not seem to get cron restored. It was working fine and suddenly it no longer does. I have Truncated the cron_schedule table, but it doesn't populate. If I run cron.php (Had to remove the block from .htaccess) it will populate the cron_schedule table, however the cron I used that previously worked, no longer works.

```
sh /home/vigeos/public_html/cron.sh
```

I have tried

```
/home/vigeos/public_html/cron.sh /home/vigeos/public_html/cron.php -mdefault
/home/vigeos/public_html/cron.sh /home/vigeos/public_html/cron.php -malways
```

and

```
/bin/sh /home/vigeos/public_html/cron.sh
```

I even ran which php and changed cron.sh to be

```
PHP_BIN=`/usr/local/bin/php`
```

Still no results.

I also tried to change permissions of cron.sh and cron.php to be 744 which also did not work. I'm running out of ideas here. I even restarted cron daemon in between.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When I try to open cron.sh with bash/shell I get: "Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc". Problems with Cronjob starts after putting magneto in an own auto on my server. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but did you ever get this resolved?  I have run into some cron issues recently and, as far as I can tell, the `cron.sh` file got corrupted at some point in the 1.9 releases.  There are tabs where there should be spaces and missing spaces around one of the `;`.  Bash scripts are VERY picky about spacing, so even if it looks right, 1 tab does NOT equal 3 spaces in Bash world.  I fixed that and everything started working again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156623)

Comment: Sure it does! If your issue is a corrupt file, you can solve it by fixing that. Feel free to alter it or make it a comment instead, but I contest it does address the OP.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Yes, I figured it out. I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/vigeos/public_html/cron.php -mdefault
/usr/local/bin/php /home/vigeos/public_html/cron.php -malways
```

This is how I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am running Magento 1.9.3.4 and had problems to get cron jobs running after moving to a new shared hosting provider. Nothing seemed to solve the problem. I figured out two things. Magento somehow preveted the cron job from running and it was using the default client version of php. In my case php 7.2, while Magento was using php 5.4.

In the end I made 2 changes as follows before setting up the Cron Jobs:

1. Edit the .htaccess file in the magento root directory as follows:

   - Search for `<Files cron.php>`
   - Comment is out as follows - `#<Files cron.php>`
2. Edit the cron.sh file as follows:

   - Search for PHP_BIN=`which php` , copy it to a new line right below it
   - Comment out the original line as follows - #PHP_BIN=`which php`
   - On the 2nd line (the copied one), replace `which php` with the path to where your
     version of php is called from (in my case it was `/opt/php54/bin/php` but it is
     normally `/usr/php/54/bin/php`). Find out from your hosting provider what this path
     is. Please note that you must first establish which version of php your Magento
     installation uses.

After this go to you CPanel Cron Jobs and set-up your cron job as follows:
Schedule setting e.g. once every 15 minutes

```
/bin/sh /full path to your site root directory/magento install directory/cron.sh
```